# Generating a random number with different digits in java

Tags: java, random

I'm trying to generate a random number with 4 different digits.

The catch is that it needs to be a **one-liner**, the solution doesn't need to be pretty.

I already tried using `Collections.shuffle(Mylist)` but I couldn't make it in one line.

My code so far:

```
List<Integer> digits = IntStream.range(0,10).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
Collections.shuffle(digits);
System.out.println(digits.subList(0,4));
```

Comment: `int i = 1234; // chosen by random dice roll`. Done. But why exactly do you want to solve this as a one-liner? Code should be a simple to read as possible. You can easily strip out newlines in Java, the result is a one-liner but completely unmaintainable and unreadable. Lines and statements aren't the same thing.

Comment: Is a number like `0962` considered valid (one that starts with a `0`)?

Comment: Delete the line breaks. Boom - one-liner.

Comment: It's for a school project and I'm bored lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure do I want to know why you need this to be a one-liner (:)) but it may be e.g.

```
Stream.of(Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9))
    .peek(Collections::shuffle)
    .map(list -> list.subList(0, 4))
    .findFirst()
    .get()
```

**EDIT**

If you need to make sure that the number will not start with `0` you can change the `map` fragment to e.g.

```
.map(list -> (list.get(0).equals(0)) ? list.subList(1, 5) : list.subList(0, 4))
```

Comment: Upvoted, but beware that 4-digit numbers starting with 0 may not be considered validly "4-digit"

Comment: ugh you are right - OP is writing about 'number' not the string/list

Comment: one more thing, how can I convert the list into an int? @m.antkowicz

Comment: basically you should iterate from the end to the beginning and add to the sum multiplying by the consecutive powers of `10`, but if you need to keep it as a one-liner you can just add `.map(list -> Integer.valueOf(list.stream().map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining())))` before the `findFirst` to cast randomed integers to strings, join them togetger and get the integer value of such string :) @Eilonlif

Comment: Thank you so much!